# How to generate computed props on the fly while accessing the Vue instance?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I was wondering if there is a way of creating computed props programatically, while still accessing the instance to achieve **dynamic values**

Something like that (`this` being undefined below)

```html
<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    ...createDynamicPropsWithTheContext(this), // helper function that returns an object
  }
}
</script>
```

On this question, there is a solution given by Linus: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/generating-computed-properties-on-the-fly/14833/4 looking like

```js
computed: {
  ...mapPropsModels(['cool', 'but', 'static'])
}
```

This works fine but the main issue is that it's fully static. Is there a way to access the Vue instance to reach upon props for example?

---

##### More context

For testing purposes, my helper function is as simple as

```js
export const createDynamicPropsWithTheContext = (listToConvert) => {
  return listToConvert?.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = curr
    return acc
  }, {})
}
```

What I actually wish to pass down to this helper function (via `this`) are props that are matching a specific prefix aka starting with any of those `is|can|has|show` (I'm using a regex), that I do have access via `this.$options.props` in a classic parent/child state transfer.

The final idea of my question is mainly to avoid manually writing all the props manually like `...createDynamicPropsWithTheContext(['canSubmit', 'showModal', 'isClosed'])` but have them populated programatically (this pattern will be required in a lot of components).

The props are passed like this

```html
<my-component can-submit="false" show-modal="true" />
```

PS: it's `can-submit` and not `:can-submit` on purpose (while still being hacked into a `falsy` result right now!).
It's for the ease of use for the end user that will not need to remember to prefix with `:`, yeah I know...a lot of difficulty just for a semi-colon that could follow Vue's conventions.

Comment: insted of "this", you can use "this.$pros".

Comment: `this` is undefined, so I don't have access to `$props`.

Comment: Where are you getting your dynamic computed from? How do you input them in the component?

Comment: You can't even do that. You can't specify a computed having the same name as a prop. You're better off writing a helper function returning all possible props, importing and spreading it into each component's props. Not to mention that props are super-flexible, you can simply pass an array of strings, unless you want `type`, `default` or `validator`.

Comment: @tao The generated computed prop would be a superset: `canSubmit` (prop) -> `convertedCanSubmit` (computed). The helper function would be used to apply a method on the prop, and exposing it via the computed. And yeah, we will be using the object syntax for the props, having it as a simple array is not possible.

Comment: By creating a superset of computed you're not solving the problem, you're duplicating it. Your template will still reference `convertedCanSubmit` in components which don't have it defined and Vue will complain about trying to access a property which has not been defined. Why not work with the prop `canSubmit` directly, especially if you can spread the props from an array having all possible props in all possible instances, with sensible defaults?

Comment: @tao Damn right, I didn't realized that if statically passed, the computed property is not reactive anyway. Like `createDynamicPropsWithTheContext['yolo']` gives `yolo: undefined` on the Vue component (devtools), meanwhile it's properly showing `yolo: 'yolo'` when using `console.log(this.$options.computed)` on a button click. Vue is not complaining but it's not working anyway. What we're doing today, is manually wrapping each involved prop like `convertMethod(canSubmit)` everywhere in the template, pretty ugly... Also, the props are not common to every component, they do have their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Vue's Discord](https://discord.com/invite/HBherRA) `Cathrine` and `skirtle` folks, I achieved to get it working!

Here is [the thread](https://discord.com/channels/325477692906536972/568037134968160256/942796547521929216) and here is the [SFC example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHNjcmlwdCBzZXR1cD5cbmltcG9ydCBNeUNoaWxkIGZyb20gJy4vTXlDaGlsZC52dWUnICBcbjwvc2NyaXB0PlxuXG48dGVtcGxhdGU+XG4gIDxteS1jaGlsZCA6aXMtc2hvd249XCJmYWxzZVwiPjwvbXktY2hpbGQ+XG4gIDxteS1jaGlsZCBpcy1zaG93bj1cImZhbHNlXCI+PC9teS1jaGlsZD5cbiAgPG15LWNoaWxkIDppcy1zaG93bj1cInRydWVcIj48L215LWNoaWxkPlxuICA8bXktY2hpbGQgaXMtc2hvd249XCJ0cnVlXCI+PC9teS1jaGlsZD5cbjwvdGVtcGxhdGU+IiwiaW1wb3J0LW1hcC5qc29uIjoie1xuICBcImltcG9ydHNcIjoge1xuICAgIFwidnVlXCI6IFwiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZmMudnVlanMub3JnL3Z1ZS5ydW50aW1lLmVzbS1icm93c2VyLmpzXCJcbiAgfVxufSIsIk15Q2hpbGQudnVlIjoiPHRlbXBsYXRlPlxuICA8ZGl2PlxuICAgIHt7IEpTT04uc3RyaW5naWZ5KGlzU2hvd24pIH19IC0ge3sgSlNPTi5zdHJpbmdpZnkobWFnaWNJc1Nob3duKSB9fVxuICA8L2Rpdj5cbjwvdGVtcGxhdGU+XG5cbjxzY3JpcHQ+XG5pbXBvcnQgeyBjb21wdXRlZCB9IGZyb20gJ3Z1ZScgIFxuICBcbmNvbnN0IG1peGluID0ge1xuICBjcmVhdGVkICgpIHtcbiAgICBjb25zdCBtYWdpY0lzU2hvd24gPSBjb21wdXRlZCgoKSA9PiB0aGlzLmlzU2hvd24gPT09IHRydWUgfHwgdGhpcy5pc1Nob3duID09PSAndHJ1ZScpXG4gICAgXG4gICAgT2JqZWN0LmRlZmluZVByb3BlcnR5KHRoaXMsICdtYWdpY0lzU2hvd24nLCB7XG4gICAgICBnZXQgKCkge1xuICAgICAgICByZXR1cm4gbWFnaWNJc1Nob3duLnZhbHVlXG4gICAgICB9XG4gICAgfSlcbiAgfVxufVxuXG5leHBvcnQgZGVmYXVsdCB7XG4gIG1peGluczogW21peGluXSxcbiAgcHJvcHM6IFsnaXMtc2hvd24nXVxufVxuPC9zY3JpcHQ+In0=) that helped me, especially this code

```js
created () {
  const magicIsShown = computed(() => this.isShown === true || this.isShown === 'true')

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'magicIsShown', {
    get () {
      return magicIsShown.value
    }
  })
}
```

Using `Object.defineProperty(this...` is helping keeping the whole state reactive and the `computed(() =>` can reference some other prop (which I am looking at in my case).

Using a JS object could be doable but I have to have it done from the template (it's a lower barrier to entry).

Still, here is the solution I came up with as a global mixin imported in every component.

```js
// helper functions
const proceedIfStringlean = (propName) => /^(is|can|has|show)+.*/.test(propName)

const stringleanCase = (string) => 'stringlean' + string[0].toUpperCase() + string.slice(1)

const computeStringlean = (value) => {
  if (typeof value == 'string') {
    return value == 'true'
  }
  return value
}

// the actual mixin
const generateStringleans = {
  created() {
    for (const [key, _value] of Object.entries(this.$props)) {
      if (proceedIfStringlean(key)) {
        const stringleanComputed = computed(() => this[key])

        Object.defineProperty(this, stringleanCase(key), {
          get() {
            return computeStringlean(stringleanComputed.value)
          },
          // do not write any `set()` here because this is just an overlay
        })
      }
    }
  },
}
```

This will scan every `.vue` component, get the passed props and if those are prefixed with either `is|can|has|show`, will create a duplicated counter-part with a prefix of `stringlean` + pass the initial prop into a method (`computeStringlean` in my case).

Works great, there is no devtools support as expected since we're wiring it directly in vanilla JS.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `setup()` hook, which receives `props` as its first argument. Pass the `props` argument to `createDynamicPropsWithTheContext`, and spread the result in `setup()`'s return (like you had done previously in the `computed` option):

```js
import { createDynamicPropsWithTheContext } from './props-utils'

export default {
  ⋮
  setup(props) {
    return {
      ...createDynamicPropsWithTheContext(props),
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-dynamic-refs-from-props?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)

Answer (score 0):

If the whole thing is for avoiding using a `:`, then you might want to consider using a simple object (or array of objects) as data source. You could just iterate over a list and bind the data to the components generated. In this scenario the only `:` used are in the objects

```js
const comps = [{
    "can-submit": false,
    "show-modal": true,
    "something-else": false,
  },
  {
    "can-submit": true,
    "show-modal": true,
    "something-else": false,
  },
  {
    "can-submit": false,
    "show-modal": true,
    "something-else": true,
  },
]

const CustomComponent = {
  setup(props, { attrs }) {
    return {
      attrs
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div
      v-bind="attrs"
    >{{ attrs }}</div>
  `
}

const vm = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    return {
      comps
    }
  },
  template: `
    <custom-component
      v-for="(item, i) in comps"
      v-bind="item"
    ></custom-component>
  `

})

vm.component('CustomComponent', CustomComponent)

vm.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>

<div id="app">{{ message }}</div>
```

Comment: This solution was already proposed in a deleted answer, unfortunately even if it works great, I need to have it defined in the template. The idea is to allow people who are not used to write JS (like python data scientists) to still be able to do things in the template easily, a JS object is on the opposite spectrum on that aspect.